# How to change drawing tablet to not map to screen?

Tags: windows-8.1, drawing, handwriting-recognition

I recently bought a  drawing tablet intending to use the handwriting recognition feature  of windows. however I stumbled across several problems. First, I would like the drawing tablet to function like a trackpad in the respect that it moves the cursor based on its current position instead of being “mapped” to the screen. Second, the text that is showing up on the screen as typed is incredibly small and makes it difficult to manipulate it; is there a way to change the size?  Last, how can I assign a key to insert the text after i have typed something instead of clicking that which is on screen. This is for Windows 8.1 and the drawing tablet is the Huion H420.

Answer (score 0):

as far as i knew there is no mouse mode on huion like it does in wacom, unless they made it now. but for sure for the older release of huion such as huion h420 it doesn't have mouse mode.

hope i helps

you can find related answers here too :
https://osu.ppy.sh/community/forums/topics/252410